# What's the difference between 301 and 302 in HTTP for Search engine

Tags: http, redirect, seo, http-status-code-302

I read this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/110227/whats-the-difference-between-301-and-302-in-http) and know What's the difference between 301 and 302 in HTTP but my question is What's the difference between 301 and 302 in HTTP for  Search engine?

Comment: What do you expect "for a search engine" to change - and how is this on topic for stackoverflow.com?

Comment: 301 redirects are permanent. They mean that the page has moved, and they request any search engine or user agent coming to the page to update the URL in their database. This is the most common type of redirect that people should use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@dani its not true...

It is called server status code and each search engine treat them as per below list:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

301 status code means the page has permanently moved to another location and search engine will pass old page value, rank and other important stuff to that newly created page. To obtain the benefit of this, one need to permanently move old page to newly created page.

302 status code means, the page is temperately not available, this code will acknowledge the search engine about temporally unavailability of the page.

Comment: both will redirect you.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with the score of the site.
This is internal matter for each search engine so there is no one true answer. 
but - on 301 (permanent) all the links will add score to the target address and in 302 they won't.

You should check out Google guidelines for this. but they are not the only search engine and they tend to change their rules every few months....

(for example, they can remove your original address once 301 from the search result and target all searches to the redirected address, and not do that if it's 302).

Comment: can you state what is false here ? I'll either correct or remove but it looks right to me now as it was 5 years ago. it's effect the way SE interpret the redirect command as permanent or temporary, from user perspective it will look the same